# Getting wrong time after Submitting Form Php Mysql Strtotime

Tags: php, mysql, forms, strtotime

I am converting **date time** format to **Strtotime** for **form submit** but getting **10sec** **wrong time**. And if the form is idle for **10 minutes** , it will get **10 minutes ago** after form submit. Please help me. i am beginner

Here is **Form.php**

```
<form action="index.php " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">   
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="hidden" name="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));?>">
```

Here is **Mysql.php**

```
$date = $_POST['date'];
```

**GET.php**

```
echo "<div id='ts'>".$timeago=get_timeago(strtotime($row['date']))."</div>";
```

Here is my **sql**

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You generate the time server side with

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));?>
```

This is the server time of the page load. It will never change on the client side, therefore this is the time you get on form submission.

Answer (score 0):

Use strtotime in **Mysql.php**, it will store the current time at insertion.

```
$date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
```